# If elif else does not detect correct string input Python

Tags: python

```
Exit=("")

Exit=str(input("Do you require another service? "))
if Exit=="Yes" or "Yeah" or "Y" or "yes":
    print("Okay")
elif Exit=="No" or "Nah" or "N" or "no":
     print("Terminating Program")
else:
    print("Terminating Program")
```

When `Exit=No`, the Yes path is chosen. Why?

Comment: `if Exit=="Yes" or "Yeah" or "Y" or "yes":` will always evalute to `True`, try `if Exit in ("Yes", "Yeah", "Y", "yes"):` instead (same for the `elif` condition)

Answer (score 2):

That's because it short-circuits and returns "Yeah" on the first logical evaluation:

```
>>> False or True or True
True
>>> False or 'exit'
'exit'
>>> bool(False or 'exit')
True
>>>
```

I recommend doing this:

```
if Exit.lower() in ('yeah', 'y', 'yes'):
    print("okay")
elif Exit.lower() in ('no', 'nah', 'n'):
    print ("Terminating Program")
else:
    print ("Terminating Program")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x in (a, b, c)` in python to check if variable `x` contains one of the values `a`, `b` or `c`:

```
Exit=("")

Exit=str(input("Do you require another service? "))
if Exit in ("Yes", "Yeah", "Y", "yes"):
    print("Okay")
elif Exit in ("No", "Nah", "N", "no"):
     print("Terminating Program")
else:
    print("Terminating Program")
```

Answer (score -1):

its easier to just check the first character in a case insensitive way

```
if exit.lower().startswith("y"): 
    print ("OK")
else:
    print("adios muchacho")
```

as to why your existing code does not work see below

`if "anything"` is always boolean `True`

`if some_condition or True` is also always `True`, regardless of whether `some_condition` is `True` or `False`

Comment: You should use `.startswith()` to prevent an index error on an empty string.